# Python: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python

I am trying to find the most recently added file of a specific type (.csv) in the folder. But am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
import glob
newest = min(glob.iglob('results/*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

Here is the error am getting:

> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

What is causing the ValueError and how to I resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that `glob.iglob('...')` returns nothing. Maybe check if you are looking in the correct place?

Comment: 1) don't provide an empty iterable, 2) catch the exception, 3) if appropriate and using Python 3.4+ then provide a `default=` argument to `min`...

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have any `.csv` files in the target location.  Try the following which should return `None` in such a case.

```
my_glob = glob.glob('results/*.csv')
newest = min(my_glob, key=os.path.getctime) if my_glob else None
```

Comment: This might work with `glob.glob` (returns a list) but `glob.iglob` (returns an iterator) will always be truthy whether or not it matched any files

Comment: Or you could write `min(my_glob, key=..., default=None)` in 3.4+

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Quick copy and paste.  Didn't notice the generator.

Comment: @Alexander Since the OP uses `iglob` this doesn't really answer the question. A solution for `iglob` would be appropriate.

Comment: @a_guest Of course it answers the question: There are no `.csv` files in the target location.  The fix doesn't require `iglob`, although it is easy to exhaust the generator via `list(glob.iglob(...))`.

Comment: @Alexander The OP asks "how to resolve \[the `ValueError`\]" - while sticking to `iglob`. The OP probably uses `iglob` (and not `glob`) for a good reason, so replacing one with another is a different story. Using `list(glob.iglob(...))` is not much different from using `glob.glob`. There are good reasons why iterators exist and why they are used. Also a more consistent solution is probably to use `[]` instead of `None` in case no files are available.